# How can I trigger an element's default event within an event handler?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, extjs3, tapestry

I have an HTML button that needs to check several conditions, and if they pass allow the default action to occur.

The following works in Firefox, but it fails in IE. I setup a click handler on the button:

```
Ext.get('send').on('click', handleSend, this, {
    preventDefault: true
});
```

which pops up one of several message boxes if one of the conditions isn't met. If all conditions are met, I remove the click listener from the button and click the button again:

```
Ext.get('send').un('click', handleSend, this);

Ext.getDom('send').click();
```

As far as I can tell, it fails in IE (and possibly other browsers) because click() isn't a standard function for a DOM element.

If the default action were a simple form submit, I could just do that after the checks pass, but we're using Tapestry 4 with a listener, which doesn't get executed on a normal form submit.

I've tried submitting the form with

```
tapestry.form.submit('composeForm', 'doSend');
```

but the `doSend` listener isn't getting called.

Conditionally allowing the default event is the best solution I've come up with, but there are a couple of options that may be possible:

1. Is there some other way to cause a Tapestry 4 listener to be fired from within Javascript?
2. Is there any way to recognize the normal form submit in my Tapestry Page and thereby trigger the listener?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdges/7/) added**

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdges/7/), the default action is to submit the form; this is prevented when the checkbox is unchecked. When checked it removes the handler, but the call to click() doesn't work in IE.

Is there a way to simulate a click in IE?

**Update**

Another snag in the problem is that I have to display an 'are you sure' dialog, so in order to give them time to answer, the event has to be stopped. If they click OK, the default action needs to occur. JSFiddle doesn't seem to have ExtJS widgets like MessageBox, so I'm not sure how to demo this behavior.

At @Ivan's suggestion I tried

```
Ext.getDom('send').fireEvent('onclick');
```

but it returns false, meaning the event is being cancelled somewhere. I then tried

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent('click', false, false);
var cancelled = Ext.getDom('send').fireEvent('onclick', evt);
```

but IE9 says that document.createEvent doesn't exist, even though this is how [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975304%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says to do it.

Comment: is there a way to see some demo page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `listener` parameter on `Form` components; from the [Tapestry 4 doc](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/components/form/form.html):

> Default listener to be invoked when the form is submitted. Invoked
>   only if another listener (success, cancel or refresh) is not invoked.

Setting this parameter to my listener method like so:

```
<binding name="listener" value="listener:doSend" />
```

causes a Tapestry form submit

```
tapestry.form.submit('myFormId');
```

to trigger the listener.

Answer (score 1):

> If all conditions are met, I remove the click listener from the button
>   and click the button again:

Don't.

You should rather check the conditions in the click handler and call stopEvent there like so:

```
Ext.get('send').on('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
    if (condition) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my example is incomplete. One of the conditions is the response to an 'are you sure' type of messagebox, so I can only allow the default action if they click OK. In order to give them time to click a button, I have to stop the event.

Comment: Right. Sorry, I didn't read the question thoroughly. I guess the right approach in this case would be triggering the Tapestry listener manually. However, I'm not familiar with that framework, so I can't help here.

Comment: Your answer was appropriate for the amount of information I provided initially, so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer does not support click. You should use fireEvent method instead e.g.

```
Ext.getDom('send').fireEvent('onclick');
```

That should work for IE. For other browsers I guess click is ok. Anyway If I should do similar task I'll try to write an adapter for tapestry and use tapestry javascript library.

Comment: I tried this, but the return value is always false meaning the event is being cancelled for some reason. I've updated the question with more info.